# Generalized maximum principle

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, poissons-equation, parabolic-pde

I search an reference where wi found the following generalized maximum principle

let $G$ be a bounded domain, $u$ be a positive solution of the Dirichlet problem for the Poisson equation $\Delta u =f$ in $G$ (so that u is continuous in $\bar G$ and  $u=0$ at the boundary), $f$ in $L^2(G)$ then 
$$
\max_{x\in G} u(x) \leq K \Vert f\Vert_{L^1(G)} (\operatorname{mes} G)^{1/n}
$$ where constant $K$ depends on the dimension $n$ only.

Thank you in advance for the help